# Conditional probability dice problem,

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Two players, Adam and Eve, are throwing a die, and the first one to get a 6, will win.

Eve is throwing first, what is the probability that Adam can win?

$P(A)$ = probability Adam to win

$P(E)$ = probability Eve to win

I know the formula for conditional probability
$ P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$

Also, I know that the conditional probability I need to calculate is $ P(A|\overline{E}) $

What I don't know is, what the intersection between these to events is.

$P(A\cap\overline{E}) = ?$

I know that the result should be $0,4545$

Also, what how do I calculate the probability for Adam to win, if the 6 was in the first 3 throws?

Thank you

Comment: You should not calculate $P(A|E^c)$. That would be the probability that Adam wins given the fact that Eve didn't win and it is essentially equal to 1 because almost surely either one of them wins. Try expressing the event that Adam wins as an infinite union of disjoint events whose probabilities will be easy to calculate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $e$ be the probability that Eve wins, and let $a$ be the probability that Adam wins.  It is reasonably clear that $e+a=1$.

We condition on the result of the first throw. If Eve throws a $6$, then she wins. This has probability $\frac{1}{6}$.

Suppose that Eve throws a non-$6$ on her first throw. This has probability $\frac{5}{6}$. If that happens, the roles of Adam and Eve are reversed, and the probability Eve wins is $a$. It follows that
$$e=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6}a=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6}(1-e).$$
We have obtained the linear equation
$$e=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6}(1-e).$$
Solve. We get $e=\frac{6}{11}$ and therefore $a=\frac{5}{11}$.

Comment: Much cleaner method than mine.  I'll have to remember that one.  Just goes to show that there can be several contrasting methods to solving a single question.

Comment: It is really your Markov chain argument without the terminology and stripped of matrices. That part of your answer is very valuable, for it points OP, and other readers, forward.

Answer (score 2):

If Eve wins, it happens on either the first throw, the third throw, the fifth throw, etc...

If Eve wins on the first throw: $\frac{1}{6}$

If Eve wins on the third throw (his second throw): She missed, he missed, she won: $\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}$

If Eve wins on the fifth throw (her personal third throw): She miss, he miss, she miss, he miss, she hit: $(\frac{5}{6})^4\cdot\frac{1}{6}$

If Eve wins on the $(2n+1)$'th throw: $(\frac{5}{6})^{2n}\cdot\frac{1}{6}$

So, calculate $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{5}{6})^{2n}\frac{1}{6}$ to add all of the possible outcomes where she wins together.

Alternatively, for Adam you have the same situation but offset a bit.  You can either take 1 and subtract the previous result, or do it again using:
$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{5}{6})^{2n+1}\frac{1}{6}$

As for winning within the first three throws, it is probably easiest to draw a tree diagram.

---

For a completely different approach, consider the absorbing markov chain with four states: He won, His turn (hasn't won yet), Her turn (hasn't won yet), She won.  There is probability of moving from His turn to He won with probability $\frac{1}{6}$, else probability $\frac{5}{6}$ to become her turn.  If he won, it remains at he won with probability $1$. Similarly so for her probabilities.

We get then an absorbing matrix in standard form with order of entries as He won, She won, His turn, Her turn as the following:

\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && \frac{1}{6} && 0\\
0 && 1 && 0 && \frac{1}{6}\\
0 && 0 && 0 && \frac{5}{6}\\
0 && 0 && \frac{5}{6} && 0\end{bmatrix}

This is in the form: \begin{bmatrix} I & S\\0 & R\end{bmatrix} and the limiting matrix becomes \begin{bmatrix} I & S(I-R)^{-1}\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}

Solving for $S(I-R)^{-1}$:
$I-R = \begin{bmatrix}1&-\frac{5}{6}\\-\frac{5}{6}&1\end{bmatrix}$

$(I-R)^{-1} = \frac{36}{11}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1&\frac{5}{6}\\ \frac{5}{6}&1\end{bmatrix}$

$S(I-R)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{6}{11} & \frac{5}{11} \\ \frac{5}{11} & \frac{6}{11}\end{bmatrix}$

So, the limiting matrix is then:

\begin{bmatrix} 1& 0 & \frac{6}{11} & \frac{5}{11} \\
0 & 1 & \frac{5}{11} & \frac{6}{11} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}

To see if it is currently Eve's turn, if Adam wins, take the element corresponding to Adam win's row, and Eve's turn column, which was how I labeled it as the first row and fourth column.  Thus, he has a $\frac{5}{11}$ chance to win if it is currently her turn.

Comment: Maybe he will figure out using your well put answer, but according to the problem Eve is throwing first, so he will have to adjust for the $2n$ and not the $2n+1$ throwing.

Comment: My mistake.  I'll fix that now as I add a second solution as well.